# Set Cookie httpOnly to false In Grails.

Tags: grails

I'm currently creating an application, in which I use code like this:

```
session.user = user.username
```

Hence I get `JSESSIONID` cookie created. But I want my client side program to read this cookie; But since its been set `HttpOnly` to `true` I can't get value from client side.

How one should change the cookie Httponly to set false in grails? So that client side code can read them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `httpOnly` setting isn't a Grails option but rather an option of the container running your application (Tomcat in your example). Thus these changes are going to be related to Tomcat more than Grails.

Normally Grails creates the `web.xml` for Tomcat at compile/runtime and while you could use the `eventConfigureTomcat` within `BuildConfig.groovy` to configure Tomcat, this would only work for development and testing environments and not production.

Thus, it's best to use [install-templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) and modify your `src/templates/war/web.xml` to have the correct value for the `httpOnly` attribute. e.g. `<Context httpOnly="false" ...` You can find out more information about configuring Tomcat from their official [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Session_cookie_configuration).